# Bug using Python 3.7 (from QGIS) and trying to install package with pip

Tags: windows, pip, qgis, python-3.7

I use QGIS 3.6 and Python 3.7 and I try to install a package with pip in command line tool under Windows 7 but I have the following message :

```
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0000188c (most recent call first):
```

My path and PYTHONPATH are well configured with link to QGIS' Python folders. The problem appeared recently with use of Python 3.7.

Comment: same problem with QGIS in 2022 trying to use a GRASS plugin

Answer (score 0):

At least for Mac recent QGIS versions seem to support only Python 3.6, not 3.7, see https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html